# Automate MYSQL database backups on openshift

Tags: mysql, openshift, database-backups

I would like to configure automated mysql database backups on openshift and I was wondering what the easiest approach is to achieve is ?

I've been reading online and one option seems to be setting up a cron job. Are there any other options ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, a `CronJob` resource is a good starting point, nothing wrong with that. Also, you might also want to check out more sophisticated solutions such as:

- [Stash](https://github.com/appscode/stash)
- Heptio  [Ark](https://github.com/heptio/ark)
- Kasten [K10](https://kasten.io/product/)

PS: I'm trying to index the available solutions via [stateful.kubernetes.sh](https://stateful.kubernetes.sh/).